# Get value of dynamically added Select input in Bootstrap Modal to show/hide text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap Modal on which I add a Select dropdown using jQuery, I then need to get the value of that dropdown and show or hide another text input.

Part of Modal `#testDetailModal`:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
    <p id="modalName"></p>
    <p id="modalTime"></p>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
    <p id="modalResponse"></p>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-2" id="statusButton">Change</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery to add the Select:

```
$('<div class="soldClass col-md-12"><div class="form-group">
<label for="test-result" class="control-label">Update result:</label>
<select class="form-control" name="test-result" id=resultSelect">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="pass">Passed</option>
  <option value="fail">Failed</option>
</select></div></div>

<div id="datePick" class="dateClass col-md-12"><div class="form-group">
<label for="test-date" class="control-label">Next test:</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="test-date"></div></div>
<div class="resultClass col-md-12">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-2" id="resultButton">Update</button>
</div>').insertAfter( "#modalTime" );
```

I want to show the `#datePick` div if the 'failed' option is chosen I am hiding it like this:

```
$('#testDetailModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  var nextDate = $('#datePick');
  nextDate.hide();
 });
```

I can't get the value of the Select to show it, this is what I have tried:

```
$('#testDetailModal').on('change','#resultSelect', function () {
   var resultOption = $('#resultSelect option:selected').val();
   if(resultOption == 'fail') {
    nextDate.show(); 
    //console.log(this.value);
    } else {
    nextDate.hide();
    } 
});
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction, I am thinking it is something to do with using the `on()` but not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: Does binding the 'on' directly to the select work? $('#resultSelect').on('change', function () {

Comment: No that didn't work it was one of the first things I tried. cheers though.

Comment: I assume //console.log(this.value); never gets called either..?

Comment: That's right, it doesn't log anything at all/

Comment: you have id=resultSelect"  it should be id="resultSelect" also if you are using multiline string in javascript I think you need to use ` instead of '

Comment: Oh my gosh! It was that typo that caused this all this time! Thanks so much. For both the pointers, the part about single quotes is it browser specific? It is working ok in FF.

Comment: Ahhh I just saw it lol good game :)

Comment: Ahhh I just saw it lol good game :)

Comment: @BryanDellinger feel free to close.